# Как из вложенного класса получить значение переменной родителя?

Tags: c#, классы

Как получить значение переменной родительского класса?

пример:

```
class main(){
 testClass parent = new testClass();
 class2level child = parent.class2level()
}

public class testClass()
{
   public string *addr*;
   testClass(){
     addr = "127.0.0.7";
   }

   public class class2level{
     class2level(){
       cnnString = *addr*;
     }
     public string cnnString {get;set;}

   }
}
```

в этом примере внутри класса class2level переменная addr из testClass недоступна

Answer (score 2):

Если наличие объекта типа `testClass` обязательно для объекта типа `class2level`, то это надо выразить в коде:

```
public class testClass()
{
   public string addr;
   public testClass() 
   {
     addr = "127.0.0.7";
   }

   public class class2level
   {
     private testClass parent;
     public class2level(testClass aParent)
     {
       parent = aParent;
     }
     public string cnnString 
     {
       get { return parent.addr; }
     }
   }
}

class main()
{
  public static void SomeMethod() 
  {
    testClass parent = new testClass();
    class2level child = new testClass.class2level(parent);
  }
}
```

Comment: а вызывать как?
testClass parent = new testClass();
 class2level child = parent.class2level(parent) ?